# When does the NodeJS request object emit events?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems I can attach multiple handlers to a `request` and they will all receive events in the right order/time. When exactly does a `request`, which has already been received and emitted by the server - when does it emit the data/end events?

```
function handler1(req, res){
   req.on('data', function(data){{
       console.log("Handler 1 data");
   });
   req.on('end', function(){{
       console.log("Handler 1 end");
   });
}

function handler2(req, res){
   req.on('data', function(data){{
       console.log("Handler 2 data");
   });
   req.on('end', function(){{
       console.log("Handler 2 end");
   });
}

http.on('request', function(req, res){
   handler1(req, res);
   handler2(req, res);
});

// Handler1 data
// Handler2 data
// Handler1 end
// Handler2 end
```

Comment: The events are issued when the HTTP request proceeds, based on network performance etc.

Comment: `http.server` emits the `request` event with a `request` object. It is therefore not possible to attach before it arrives.Is it up to timing to be able to catch these events?

Comment: @bbb___ddd - See what I added to my answer on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request object is an `EventEmitter` object.  As such, it emits events and anyone can add listeners for those events.

In the case of the request object, it emits events that correspond with networking.  The `data` event is emitted when some data has arrived (from the request body).  If you have more than one listener for the `data` event, then each listener will see each `data` event with the exact same data.

The `end` event is emitted where there is no more data to from the request body (all data has arrived).

Until you attach some means of reading the data from the incoming request (such as a `data` event listener), the data is queued and will be held in memory.  This gives you a chance to attach the listener even after the data has already started arriving without any worry about missing any of the data.  In node.js, many streams work this way.  Data doesn't start flowing through the listeners until you attach at least one listener for the data.

Comment: "Data doesn't start flowing through the listeners until you attach at least one listener for the data." This is what I was looking for. Any source on it?

Comment: @bbb___ddd - Read the 4th paragraph here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Comment: @bbb___ddd - Since the request inherits from the stream object, you can read about the `data` event on a stream also: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data